# Expo using UIWebView even when useWebKit set to true

Tags: ios, expo, wkwebview

I’m getting a warning from Apple regarding the usage of UIWebView in my expo app (in Testflight). From the documentation, I thought that using useWebKit={true} would use the WKWebView version, but after enabling it and uploading to the store, I continue to get the same warning. My WebView looks like this:

I've tried setting the  useWebKit={true}.

```
<WebView
style={styles.container}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}
useWebKit={true}
cacheEnabled={false}
source={{ uri: this.state.url  }}
>
</WebView>
```

I expected Expo to use the WKWebView thus avoiding the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread:

https://forums.expo.io/t/received-mail-from-apple-about-the-deprecated-api-uiwebview/27117.

They have removed instances of using UIWebView, But some of third party dependencies are still using *UIWebView*. They're still planning to remove completely all instances of *UIWebView* in the future. Even the current release which is SDK 35(at the time of writing) some reported receiving the email and Some didn't. I receive the email and I am using **SDK 33**. I'll upgrade and see where it goes. For now I'll check if ***useWebKit*** props will get rid of this issue using **SDK 35**.